# Which one to use: "I have constructed skills" or "I have built skills"?

Tags: expressions

I want to express I improved and got new skills and now also I do as well since I started to work.

1) I have constructed skills.

2) I have built skills.

Which one is correct? Or is there other way to express this in common?

Comment: Although *constructed* and *built* have the same meaning, **built** sounds more appropriate with *skills* as in ***they have built (up) a wide range of musical skills by interning with some leading bands*** // *it takes time but he has **built his skill** through long and hard practice.* Note: you can use 'built' with 'skill' but it is somewhat more usual to use **developed** in this context: "they **developed** their skills through diligent practice."

Comment: I agree that "developed" would be better, but built is the only one of the two words that could fit.  "Construct" is more about combining or arranging components to make something.  You don't construct a skill.

Comment: Neither, ever. Native speakers do not *construct* or *build* skills.
*developed* if you want a construction-industry simile that matches *constructed* or *built*.
*Gained* would be suitable; *Nurtured my…* marginally suitable. *Expanded… https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=developed&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB718GB718&oq=developed&aqs=chrome..69i57.3430j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - Not true.  ***Skill building*** is a very popular term.https://www.familyeducation.com/entertainment-activities/skill-building-activities

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Also _acquired skills_, if this isn't old fashioned by now.

Comment: Uh… don't you think English Student's *built up* skills is greatly preferable? I haven't been in the recruitment market for a while but I never once heard anyone suggest he'd *built skills* and if he had, I'd hope that would still be neither normal nor comparable to the rather different eymology of *skill building*.

*Acquired* is fine and dandy and don't you think that's comparable to *building* or *developing* skills in pretty-much the same way it would be for *houses*.

Answer (score 3):

Generally an individual ***learns** new skills*,  then ***improves** on their skills* until they ***master** those skills*.

---

**Learn** is defined by [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/learn) as:

> to acquire knowledge of or skill in by study, instruction, or experience

---

**Improve** is defined by [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/improve?s=t) as:

> to bring into a more desirable or excellent condition:

---

**Master** is defined by [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/master?s=t) as:

> to make oneself master of; become an adept in:

---

You can use either one depending on how much experience you have with the skill set. Generally if you have (*using your phrase as a given example*):

- no experience in the skill, you will be *learning* that skill

  - e.g. *I have learned new skills.*
- some experience in the skill, you will be *improving* that skill

  - e.g. *I have improved on my [new] skills.*
- lots of experience in the skill, you will have *mastered* that skill

  - e.g. *I have mastered my skills.*

Comment: @user1808808 If anything is unclear, or you need any further clarification, please let me know or please kindly accept the answer :)